# combinations of sizes for shipping

Tags: ruby, algorithm, list, grouping

I've got a bunch of products with sizes to ship and I need to find out the cheapest rate.

Given a shipment made out of sizes, say [1,3,3,5] I need to decide how to ship - all together or separate. However it's not as simple as [1,3,3,5] or 1 & 3 & 3 & 5, i need all of the possible combinations something like:

```
[
[[1,3,3,5]],           ( 1 shipment )
[[1],[3,3,5]],         ( 2 shipments )
[[1,3],[3,5]],         ( 2 shipments )
[[1,3,3],[5]],         ( 2 shipments )
[[1,5],[3,3]],         ( 2 shipments ) 
[[1,3],[3],[5]],       ( 3 shipments )
[[1],[3],[3],[5]]      ( 4 shipments )
]
```

( etc - many more i assume )
I've tried combinations from the facets gem but it's not quite what i'm after, and I'm not sure how else to approach this problem. I understand it probably has a name and a solution if only I knew the name :)

I understand there could be a lot of combinations, but the initial array of sizes won't be larger than 7 or so.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: At an array size of 7 you got 7! combinations which are 5040.
This sounds to me like a P to NP Problem. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P_versus_NP_problem

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I guess you want to generate **[the partitions of a set](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_of_a_set)**.

[**Here is very good explanation and working code to do it.**](http://compprog.wordpress.com/2007/10/15/generating-the-partitions-of-a-set/)

But doing this is not a very good idea as it leads to **[Combinatorial Explotion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combinatorial_explosion)**.

There are [image] such things for `n`.

I think you have a **[knapsack problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_knapsack_problems)** and [**dynamic programming**](http://www.topcoder.com/tc?module=Static&d1=tutorials&d2=dynProg) is the right way to solve it.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe a look here http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Packing_problem and here http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem could be inspiring...

Answer (score 1):

For `N <= 7`, you can simply be exhaustive:

In C-ish pseudo-code with bitmask:

```
result = ()
subsets( int x, list current )
    if ( x == 0 )
        result.append( current )

    for ( int i = x; i >= 0; i = ( ( i - 1 ) & x ) )
        subsets( x ^ i, append i to current )
```

where "append i to current" means getting the indices, putting it in a list and appending it.  If you want to play with optimization, you can even memoize it.

Answer (score 0):

This problem is known as the Variable-Sized Bin Packing Problem in the combinatorial optimization literature. Since it generalizes Bin Packing, it's NP-hard, but techniques like branch and bound should do a reasonable job on instances too large to be handled by brute force.